# How to customize WebViewPage executation output?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am going to inject some elements in every view of our Asp.Net MVC application. so to do that (I found this: [Custom WebViewPage inject code when razor template is rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860151/custom-webviewpage-inject-code-when-razor-template-is-rendering) answer) I have subclassed the `WebViewPage` and I have overridden the `ExecutePageHierarchy` like below:

```
   public override void ExecutePageHierarchy()
    {
        base.ExecutePageHierarchy();
        string output = Output.ToString();
        if (MyHelper.InitializationRequired)
            output = MyHelper.GetPageHeader() + output + MyHelper.GetPageFooter();
        //--------------
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(output);
        Response.End();
    }
```

by this code we can wrap all of the output markup with some header and some footer elements such as scripts or additional tags which i want to do that.

**BUT in this way we lost the `Layout` completely!** because of clearing the response.

my main question is that, **how to inject some HTML markups exactly before or exactly after `WebViewPage`'s output** by preserving the content of response which maybe there are some other views or the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a trick to do it by this way:

```
 public override void ExecutePageHierarchy()
    {
        var tmp = OutputStack.Pop();
        var myWriter = new StringWriter();
        OutputStack.Push(myWriter);
        base.ExecutePageHierarchy();

        tmp.Write(
            string.Format("<div> Header of [{0}]</div> {1} <div> Footer of [{0}]</div>",
            VirtualPath,
            myWriter.ToString()));
    }
```

it works well generally and it wraps the output of view by header and footer. but in my scenario i should able to access to some flags which will assigned on executing view. so i must check them after view execution:

```
 public override void ExecutePageHierarchy()
    {
        var tmp = OutputStack.Pop();
        var myWriter = new StringWriter();
        OutputStack.Push(myWriter);
        base.ExecutePageHierarchy();
        if (MyHelper.InitializationRequired)
           tmp.Write(
            string.Format("<div> Header of [{0}]</div> {1} <div> Footer of [{0}]</div>",
            VirtualPath,
            myWriter.ToString()));
        else
           tmp.Write(myWriter.ToString());
    }
```

this approach works well for me. so i posted it, maybe help some one;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the layout system of MVC ... It's full featured to have a master layout schema :=)